# Error after updating to the latest version Azure SDK

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, azure

After I updated to the newest version the Azure SDK I have started to get this error several times each day when I press build in Visual Studio. The only way for me to fix it at the moment is to restart my visual studio.

The error I get is:
**Windows Azure Tools: Invalid access to memory location**

Is there someone else that have got this error? And also what did you do to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

**Update 2012-08-28:** The same error still exist in VS2012 and Azure 1.7 SDK. However the frequency have gone down with VS2012.

Comment: Maybe I also should write that the newest version was 1.5 when I was posting this question. Today the version is 1.6 but I still have the same problem

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/736847/windows-azure-devfabric-invalid-access-to-memory-location

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio as an administrator?

Comment: Yes I run it as a admin. I have given up this error tbh :) I was at TechEd in the summer and talked with the Azure guys and so on. No one have been able to solve it so it's just to live with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that [was fixed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2013/10/31/compute-emulator-invalid-access-to-memory-location.aspx) in Windows 8.1, however for older versions of Windows there is a [hotfix available](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2588507)

Comment: I have stopped to work with this for ages ago. However I'm happy to hear that they have fixed that bug.

Thanks alot for replying with a fix!

Comment: Verified the fix with my old colleges that still works with this. It works now. Thanks alot avs099!

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem as you, and I've tried it all.

Upgrading, downgrading, reboot, re-install. Getting all windows updates and so on.

But I finaly found what was causing my problems. It was the database, or I should say my sql express database that was causing the problem.

Azure SDK will by default create the DB that it needs on a express edition. After changing what DB azure should use, everything works perfectly.

[Details on how to switch to another DB:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433134.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when you installed the SDK, but a [hotfix has been issued](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/10/01/windows-azure-sdk-1-5-update-released-previous-1-5-20830-1814-latest-1-5-20928-1904.aspx). You can't tell by going to the download page. Just reinstall the SDK.

Comment: Tried this and it did not solve the problem. Thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: I've installed the lastest as of 4/29/2012 and still get the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had de same problem and after try everything, i search and install all the windows updates available, thid include, vs2010 sp1, windows 7 sp1, and a lot more.
after that everything start to work fine.

hope it helps.

Comment: Tried this also and it did not solve the problem. Thanks for trying to help me!